# remove empty option from ng-select

Tags: angular5, angular-ngselect

How can I avoid the empty value in the ng-select.
My intention is that whenever I have a boolean property in the component set to true - there is only one record in the validFiltersData - then I want the drop down to be selected on it and disabled, so the user cannot select the empty option.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let validFilter of validFiltersData; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="validFilter.Values && validFilter.Values.length > 0" 
       class="filter col-md-4 reportFilter">
    <ng-select [items]="validFilter.Values"  bindLabel="Text" 
                [(ngModel)]="validFilter.selectedValue" 
                 [ngClass]="{'input-md': true,  'ng-invalid': 
                                                  !validFilter.IsValid }">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so by using the placeholder property - setting it to the relevant value of the model:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let validFilter of validFiltersData; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="validFilter.Values && validFilter.Values.length > 0" 
   class="filter col-md-4 reportFilter">
       <ng-select [items]="validFilter.Values"  bindLabel="Text"
            placeholder = {{validFilter.DefaultSelectedFilterText}} 
             [(ngModel)]="validFilter.selectedValue" 
             [ngClass]="{'input-md': true,  'ng-invalid': 
             !validFilter.IsValid }">
       </ng-select>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```